# javascript, function, mathrandom, array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm supposed to do a math exercise with subtractions for a basic Javascript course. The exercise has to contain 5 exercises with 5 prompt-windows (e.g "10-7=", "5-1=" etc). The first number has to be bigger than the second one.

Therefore, I need to create a function that generates two random numbers and then returns them in an array. Before it returns, it has to make sure that the number in position 0 is bigger than the number in position 1, the random numbers has to be between 1-10. If the person answers the question right, an alert window should pop up and say "Right!" and the same if it's wrong.

My code so far is this, and I'm aware that it's not completely right. What's wrong? How can I make it right?

```js
function number ()
{
    var array = [a, b];
    var numbers = Math.floor(Math.random()*10)+1;

    array[0] = a ;
    array[1] = b ;
    if (a <= b)
    a = a+b;
    b = a-b;
    a = a-b;

    return a + b;
}

var mathQuestion = a + " - " + b +" = ";
var answer = a - b;

for(var i =0; i<6; i++) {
    var yourAnswer = parseInt(prompt(mathQuestion));

    if (yourAnswer === answer) {
        alert("Right!");
    }
    else {
        alert("Wrong!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using variables `a` and `b` which you have never defined before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve but I considered to have a look at your code to kind of improve it.

This code is working fine, so please have a look `:)`

```js
function getTask() {
  var array = [];
  var numberA = getRandomNumber()
  var numberB = getRandomNumber()

  if (numberA > numberB) {
    array[0] = numberA;
    array[1] = numberB;
  } else {
    array[0] = numberB;
    array[1] = numberA;
  }
  return array;
}

function getRandomNumber() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
}


let questionCount = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < questionCount; i++) {
  let numbers = getTask()
  var mathQuestion = numbers[0] + " - " + numbers[1] + " = ";
  var answear = numbers[0] - numbers[1];

  var yourAnswear = parseInt(prompt(mathQuestion));
  if (yourAnswear === answear)
    alert("Right!");
  else
    alert("Wrong!");
}
```

`Note`: The problems was that you were missing the declaration of `a and b`. Put the keyword `var` before the values.

Answer (score 0):

You can impress your teacher with [ternary operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:), [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) array methods and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/deYYMg?editors=1012)

```
const getRandom = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
const ask = () => {
    const numbers = [getRandom(), getRandom()].sort((a, b) => b - a)
    alert(
        prompt(numbers.join(' - ') + ' = ') == numbers[0] - numbers[1] ?
            'Right!' : 'Wrong!'
    )
}


for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    ask();
}
```